# extract first sequence of numeric characters after one of a numeber of strings

Tags: regex, hive

I have a few strings

```
'delivery|1111111'
'order|22222222'
'smth else|3333333'
```

I need to extract the first sequence of numeric characters after `delivery|` or `order|`.

If it's just one I do

```
select regexp_extract('delivery|1111111|22222222', 'delivery\\|(\\d+)', 1);
```

and get `1111111`, but when I try for both

```
select regexp_extract('order|22222222|11111111', '(delivery\\|(\\d+)|order\\|(\\d+))', 1);
```

I get `order|22222222`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Hive regexes are Java regexes, try this regex: `(?:delivery|order)\\|(\\d+)`

The problem is that you're using three capturing groups, and the group you're selecting captures the entire string.